# How to add offsetTime to UTC time to get the right ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java, date, zoneddatetime

I want to convert a UTC time to a localisedDateTime or zonedDateTime.

I have the following input: `2013-07-10 02:52:49,-44.490947,171.220966` Where the date time is UTC time zone.

I get my zoneId with latitude and longitude which gives me `Pacific/Auckland`.

With this, I try to get the local time at zone`Pacific/Auckland` from the timestamp and expect as shows the following [conversion](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20130710T025200&p1=1440&p2=22&p3=240) the result I am looking for.

Playing around with my timeStamp I get:

`2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]`.

But I am looking for the following output:

`2013-07-10T14:52:49`

I don't think that manipulating the string the change it to a number and add manually is the right answer.

I am sure that we can do this with dates but I am new to Java and after surfing for hours I have not yet found my solution.

The solutions below while they seem valid show the date `2013-07-9` and so does it in my code. So if the website shows the time im expecting why are we not getting the same result?

Comment: It sounds like you misunderstood. The +12:00 in the string mean that 12 hours have already been added compared to UTC. So to convert to UTC you need to *subtract* them again. The correct UTC time for the same instant/moment is 2013-07-09T14:52:49+00:00, so the **nineth** of July. And you are correct: you shouldn’t do it as string manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you capture the date time

> 2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

, capture it as ZonedDateTime, so that it will have the zone as UTC+12:00.

On that use `dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));` to convert the date time into UTC+0 HRS which results 2013-07-10T14:52:49

If you get above data time as a string, then you can convert it to UTC ZonedDateTime as below.

```
    String time = "2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time);
    ZoneId zoneId = zdt.getZone();
    System.out.println(zdt);
    System.out.println(zdt.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId).toLocalDateTime());
    zdt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

Output:

```
2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]
2013-07-10T02:52:49
2013-07-09T14:52:49Z[UTC]
```

Comment: It’s correct and therefore gives the correct result (`2013-07-09T14:52:49Z[UTC]`). `zdt.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId)` is redundant, and normally you would not want to convert to `LocalDateTime`, throwing away the time zone information.

Comment: Why do you have the 9th on your date then rather than the 10th? Auckland being in advance on UTC i would expect `(2013-07-10T14:52:49Z[UTC]). `

Comment: @SantaClauze If the time in Auckland ticks *ahead* of the UTC time, then it should be *later* in Auckland, for instance, if the UTC time is 06:15, then it's 12 hours *later* in Auckland, that is, 18:45. The very instant of `2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]` is the same as `2013-07-09T14:52:49Z[UTC]`.